# Detect when Backbone has finished a model fetch

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I can't seem to figure out which event to listen to when fetching data for a model. Usually when I'm doing it for a collection, I listen to the sync event. However, it seems like that doesn't work for models.

So, how do I know when my model is done fetching? Which event does it trigger?

Edit: Here's the beginning part of my view that is using the model:

```
var HomeContent = BaseView.extend({

        initialize: function(options) {
            self = this;
            this.academyID = this.options.parent.academyID;
            this.model = new AcademyModel({academyID: this.academyID});
            this.model.on('sync', function() {
                console.log('sync');
            });
            this.model.fetch();

        }
```

Comment: `sync` does work, as far as I can tell. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/g7grC/

Comment: Can you check out my code I just added and see if I'm missing something here? My model doesn't seem to be triggering the sync event.

Comment: Still working. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/g7grC/1/ Please use my Fiddle as a basis to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

fetch returns a jQuery promise. Just use something like:

```
this.model.fetch().done(function() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is in the docs:

```
Accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which are both passed (model,response, options) as arguments.
```